# I want to download jdk windows 32 bit

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin.android

Where can I find JDK for Windows 32-bit for Android Studio, the official site for Oracle found only 64-bit versions, can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: In Oracle Java download site, look for Windows x86

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Kindly check the system configuration part as well. Android Studio needs SE8 I guess. Use Windows x86 link from very first table.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow steps below -

1. Open in browser -  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. Click on Accept License Agreement (radio button)
3. Click on link **"jdk-8u201-windows-i586.exe"** - to download Windows x86 (windows 32 bit) version of JDK.

Hope it could help you.